RTK toolkit network request fails after adding auto renewal of access token with firebase
I'm having a problem here after adding the auto renewal code that I found here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#automatic-re-authorization-by-extending-fetchbasequery of the access token when I get a 401 unauthorized error from the api, it seems now all my endpoints do not work and fail with a network failed error message from react native. I'm using firebase auth for user sign in and sign up in my app. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: BACKEND_BASE_URL,
    prepareHeaders: (headers, {getState, endpoint}) => {
        let accessToken = (getState() as RootState).appState.accessToken;
        if (accessToken) {
            headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
        }
        return headers;
    },
});

const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<
    string | FetchArgs,
    unknown,
    FetchBaseQueryError
> = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
    console.log("Error", result)
    if (result.error && result.error.status === 401) {
        console.log("401 baby")
        // try to get a new token
        try {
            // Store the new token
            const accessToken = await auth?.currentUser?.getIdToken();
            if (!accessToken) {
                throw Error()
            }
            api.dispatch(setAccessToken(accessToken));
            // api.dispatch(setRefreshToken(user.refreshToken));
            // Retry the initial query
            result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
        } catch (error) {
            api.dispatch(setLoggedInUser(null));
            api.dispatch(setRefreshToken(null));
            api.dispatch(setAccessToken(null));
        }
    }
    return result
}

export const backendApiSlice = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'backendApiSlice',
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        checkoutOrder: builder.mutation<Order, { products: ProductQuantity[] }>({
            query: ({products}) => ({
                url: ENDPOINTS.checkoutOrder,
                method: 'POST',
                body: {
                    products,
                },
            }),
        }),
        cancelOrder: builder.mutation<Order, { orderId: string }>({
            query: ({orderId}) => ({
                url: ENDPOINTS.cancelOrder,
                method: 'POST',
                body: {
                    orderId,
                },
            }),
        }),
        register: builder.mutation<{
            user: { displayName: string, email: string, uid: string, emailVerified: boolean },
            customToken: string
        }, RegistrationRequest>({
            query: (registrationData) => ({
                url: ENDPOINTS.registerUser,
                method: 'POST',
                body: registrationData,
            }),
        }),
        getUserAddress: builder.query<Address, void>({
            query: () => ({
                url: ENDPOINTS.userAddress,
                method: 'GET',
            }),
        }),
        getUserOrders: builder.query<Order[], void>({
            query: () => ({
                url: ENDPOINTS.userOrders,
                method: 'GET',
            }),
        }),
        sendOtp: builder.mutation<void, SendOtpRequest>({
            query: (otpData) => ({
                url: ENDPOINTS.sendOtp,
                method: 'POST',
                body: otpData,
            }),
        }),
        verifyOtp: builder.mutation<{ valid: boolean }, VerifyOTPRequest>({
            query: (otpData) => ({
                url: ENDPOINTS.verifyOtp,
                method: 'POST',
                body: otpData,
            }),
        }),
        validateLocation: builder.mutation<AddressResult, { latitude: number; longitude: number }>({
            query: ({latitude, longitude}) => ({
                url: ENDPOINTS.validateLocation,
                method: 'POST',
                params: {latitude, longitude},
            }),
        }),
        validatePhoneNumber: builder.mutation<{ valid: boolean }, PhoneNumberValidationRequest>({
            query: ({countryCode, phoneNumber}) => ({
                url: ENDPOINTS.validatePhoneNumber,
                method: 'POST',
                body: {countryCode, phoneNumber},
            }),
        }),
        subscribeToMailList: builder.mutation<{ message: string }, { email: string }>({
            query: ({email}) => ({
                url: ENDPOINTS.subscribeToMailList,
                method: 'POST',
                body: {email},
            }),
        }),
        supportedRegionCoordinates: builder.query<Array<{ latitude: number; longitude: number }> | null, void>({
            query: () => ({
                url: ENDPOINTS.supportedRegionCoordinates,
                method: 'GET',
            }),
            transformResponse: (response: { result: Array<{ latitude: number; longitude: number }> }) => {
                return response.result;
            },
        }),
        adminOrders: builder.query<ApiResponse<Order>, { startDate: string, endDate?: string }>({
            query: ({startDate, endDate}) => ({
                url: ENDPOINTS.adminOrders,
                method: 'GET',
                params: {startDate, endDate},
            }),
        }),
    }),
});

export const {
    useCheckoutOrderMutation,
    useRegisterMutation,
    useVerifyOtpMutation,
    useSendOtpMutation,
    useGetUserAddressQuery,
    useGetUserOrdersQuery,
    useValidatePhoneNumberMutation,
    useValidateLocationMutation,
    useSubscribeToMailListMutation,
    useCancelOrderMutation,
    useSupportedRegionCoordinatesQuery,
    useAdminOrdersQuery
} = backendApiSlice;

export default backendApiSlice.reducer;

